# why the bitnami wamp stack is so much complicated? I am irritated. Bitnami needs to add chat for customer troubleshooting

Tags: bitnami

bitnami wamp stack is so much complicated, not resolving troubleshooting issues properly!  I am irritated. Bitnami needs to add chat for customer troubleshooting.

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. A Bitnami native installer includes everything you need to run your Bitnami-packaged application of choice. Once downloaded, you can launch it and it will provide a step-by-step wizard. The installation and configuration is completely automated. We also include a Console tool ("use_XXX" binary inside the installation) that loads the configuration of that installation so you use the components that the stack installed. We also provide support in our [community forum](https://community.bitnami.com/) to all the users who use our solutions.

Comment: Thank you for reply and guidance. Yesterday i have successfully downloaded Bitnami wordpress on my local machine and learning it step by step. Before that i was confused because i had downloaded Bitnami Wamp Stack and i was searching www folder in the folder structure where i was going to paste/install Bitnami Wordpress!! I was confused because a small custom php effect was not seen, and .dll files missing errors.. etc.   But Bitnami website Needs more simplicity in explaining the troubleshooting. Community forum seems complex! Make tabulars sections for wordpress troubleshooting etc! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

the installation process will create several sub-directories under the installdir directory: servers, languages, application files, ... Application files are stored in the installdir/apps/APPNAME/htdocs directory.

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/faq/windows-faq/#what-is-the-directory-structure

If you are developing on top of an AMP Stack or customizing any Bitnami Stack, your files (like JavaScript files) may be cached by the server and even you modify them your changes will not appear to be applied. You can disable opcache in PHP by editing the installdir\php\php.ini file and setting the opcache.enable option to 0.

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/infrastructure/lamp/#how-to-disable-the-cache-in-the-server

Comment: Hello Jota Martos, Thank you again. Now I am learning Bitnami Wamp Stack, Wordpress step by step.